# Fetch time series from Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to fetch a list of prices from google big query using the following query :

```
    query_request = service.jobs()
    query_data = {
            'query': (
                '''
                SELECT
                    open 
                FROM
                   timeseries.price_2015
                ''')
        }

    query_response = query_request.query(
            projectId=project_id,
            body=query_data).execute()
```

The table contains 370000 records, but the query loads only the first 100000. I guess I am hitting some limit? Can you tell how I can fetch all records for the 'price' column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of rows returned is limited by the lesser of either the maximum page size or the maxResults property. See more in [Paging Through list Results](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#paging-through-list-results)

Consider using [Jobs: getQueryResults](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/getQueryResults)  or [Tabledata: list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/list) where you can call those API in loop passing PageToken from previous response to next call and collecting whole set on client side